# set an attribute with or without check

Tags: java, if-statement, coding-style, jtextfield

I've learnt that's better first to check if an attribute is already as I like and only then to set it again. If I'm wrong, just say it!

Short example: If I want to clear an JTextField (set text to ""), should I check the existing value first and if it's not yet correct, set a blank string.

```
...
if (!jtextfield.getText().equals("")) {
    jtextfield.setText("");
}
...
```

Or should I set the text directly without checking first?

```
...
jtextfield.setText(""); 
...
```

Which of these versions is better? Which do you prefer?

Comment: If your only intention is to set it to blank irrespective of what is contains then no need of checking.

Comment: @Algorithmist thanks, helped me a lot to improve my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if `jTextfield` returns null or not is a can be a good practice.

```
if (jtextfield!=null) 
     jtextfield.setText("");
```

Comment: how it is going to help anyway?Even if it is null then now you are setting it to "" which is fine

Comment: How is it possible that `jtextfield.getText()` could be `null`?

Comment: @Algorithmist Asker wants like that.I can not know why he set to "".

Comment: @Reimeus AFAIK it can be null.Can't it be?

Comment: @ihsankocak Yes it can be.But how does it matter to check for null?